# G++ always fails with undefined reference to _Unwind_GetIPInfo

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu, g++, apt

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04 on my Asus EeePC netbook, and have a problem with G++. Compiling any program using G++, even a simple "Hello World", whether using iostream, cstdio, or stdio.h, fails with the message:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `_Unwind_GetIPInfo@GCC_4.2.0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I use Synaptic Package Manager. Before the upgrade, Ubuntu provided GCC 4.4, though I had also installed GCC 4.5 (gcc-4.5) via another repository. GCC 4.5 is now the default in Ubuntu 11.04.

I think the problem may be to do with libgcc. I tried reinstalling GCC, but I couldn't remove libgcc: first of all, Synaptic Package Manager, reported that there are broken packages somewhere, and stopped my attempt; but I also noted that to remove libgcc would require the removal of almost every application, including apt and Firefox.

I also tried the gcc-snapshot package; unfortunately, it gives the same error listed above.

Is there any way to use Synaptic Package Manager to obtain a recent, working version of G++?

Comment: I _am_ assuming you have **recompiled** the programs after upgrading the compiler?

Comment: Yes, the error is a compile error.

Comment: Erm. Obviously :) Colour me silly

Comment: @user643722 try compiling with `-v` g++ option, it provides lots of info potentially useful for your case

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. It made me look again. I previously linked often to the g95 Fortran compiler's (version 0.92 of Jun 24 2009) runtime library from C++, and had set the first entry of the `LIBRARY_PATH` env variable to `$G95/g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/4.0.3/` Removing this entry fixed my problem. g95 still works btw. Alas, Dmitry, you have no answer I can formally accept. I will accept the answer of whoever can succinctly rephrase that.

Comment: @user643722 since you found the reason yourself, it's fair if you post the answer to your question and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC-4.6 was finding an older, incompatible version of libgcc.a in `$LIBRARY_PATH`; in my case it was the also the first entry in `$LIBRARY_PATH`. The entry was `$G95/g95-install/lib/gcc-lib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/4.0.3/` and relates to the G95 Fortran compiler. I had done this myself some time ago, in the .bash_profile, as I would, at that time, often link C++ programs to the libfortran.a library in that same directory. Removing this entry fixed my problem. In future I would use the -L switch to GCC for such situations.

Answer (score 0):

The operative word: **--reinstall**

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++ --reinstall
```

Add all package you suspect are corrupted

Comment: This gives a lot of messages of the form: Note, selecting 'libstdc++6' for regex 'libstdc+' then concluded by words leading to: The following packages have unmet dependencies: libstdc++6-4.5-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.5-15ubuntu1 is to be installed. What is 4.4.5-15ubuntu1? How can this help me? Do you have an idea what has happened?

Comment: You can quote the names with `libstdc++6` (i missed the 6, sry). Further you can see whether you have uncompleted apt runs that can autorepair using `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6 --reinstall` which recommended I first clear out some packages using autoremove. I did this, and then ran it again. Same error. I guess I "suspect" g++ and libgcc1, but `sudo apt-get install libgcc1 --reinstall` or `sudo apt-get install -f libgcc1 --reinstall` change nothing either; so too with g++.