# '_Unwind_GetIPInfo' symbol

Tags: c++, c, libstdc++, cppunit

I m developing unit test using cppunit.

I build and installed cppunit library then I build and install my unit test binary.

And when I launch the unit test binary I get the following error:

```
 can't resolve symbol '_Unwind_GetIPInfo' in lib '/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6'.
```

This error is generated only if the test will return failure. If the test reurn OK I did not got this error

Any idea about this error?

Comment: Looks like you used different stdc libs for compilation and runtime, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855343/g-always-fails-with-undefined-reference-to-unwind-getipinfo

Comment: @j.holetzeck that's it. thank you. put your comment as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you used different stdc libs for compilation and runtime, check [G++ always fails with undefined reference to _Unwind_GetIPInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855343/g-always-fails-with-undefined-reference-to-unwind-getipinfo)