# clang linker error on build.make:88 and undefined reference to 'Unwind_GetIPInfo'

Tags: cmake, linker, raspberry-pi3, ros, ros2

ROS2 rolling installation process on Raspberry Pi Model 3B running Raspbian buster v10

```
stderr: osrf_testing_tools_cpp
/usr/bin/ld: ../../src/memory_tools/libmemory_tools.so: undefined reference to `_Unwind_GetIPInfo'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [test/memory_tools/CMakeFiles/test_memory_tools.dir/build.make:88: test/memory_tools/test_memory_tools] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1255: test/memory_tools/CMakeFiles/test_memory_tools.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2


Failed   <<< osrf_testing_tools_cpp [2min 24s, exited with code 2]
```

I don't know where to start, I was able to pull up the build.make file and line 88 says this.

```
86 test/memory_tools/test_memory_tools: test/memory_tools/CMakeFiles/test_memory_tools.dir/link.txt
87  @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --bold --progress-dir=/home/pi/ros2_rolling/build/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_2) "Linking CXX executable test_memory_tools"
88  cd /home/pi/ros2_rolling/build/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/test/memory_tools && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test_memory_tools.dir/link.txt --verbose=$(VERBOSE)
```

I think this link.txt is important as well.

```
/usr/bin/clang++     CMakeFiles/test_memory_tools.dir/test_memory_tools.cpp.o  -o test_memory_tools  -Wl,-rpath,/home/pi/ros2_rolling/build/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/src/memory_tools -pthread ../../src/memory_tools/libmemory_tools.so ../../lib/libgtest_main.a /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so ../../lib/libgtest.a -pthread -lpthread
```

Comment: Can you open `
osrf_testing_tools_cpp/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/src/memory_tools/
` and check if there is a `libmemory_tools.so` file in there?

Comment: @2b-t I was able to find `libmemory_tools.so` but it was under `build/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/src/memory_tools`

Comment: From what I know it might happen if different libraries are mixed. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5934830/9938686)...